# SIP End Call with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sip

I am creating an application where the user can initiate an x-lite call by clicking on a number from Browser. Initiating call was pretty easy. All I had to do, was add `<a href="SIP: <numer>">`. I am unable to find a method to end the call from javascript.

I checked out vicidialer. They have a method where I can have an eyebeam minimised and running in the background the and call and hangup buttons somehow send command to it. Looking to implement something like that.

Thanks for the help in advance.
--Manish

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done, at least not with pure Javascript.

Launching your SIP dialler is being done by registering the `sip:` URI scheme handler in your browser.

Once that URI has been launched there's no further interaction with your browser.

Comment: Can you throw some light on how vicidialer does this? They have a mechanism which triggers eyebeam while it is minimised in the background, both for making the call and ending it?

Comment: maybe they're abusing the SIP URI syntax to send "out of band" messages to eyebeam?  i.e. clicking on `sip:hangup` might do a hangup, even though it's not a legal SIP URI.

Comment: It's not far away from being possible in pure javascript http://blog.chromium.org/2012/04/chromes-webrtc-roadmap.html.

Comment: @sipwiz yeah, I know about WebRTC, but as it stands this question is about browser control of an external SIP client, not building SIP _into_ a browser.